# Python: Cut out the square from the raster. The square has a 30 kilometres (18 miles) side length and has the center in the given coordinates

Tags: python, raster, gdal

The following code displays the coordinates for a city in Poland given by the user, for example **Kock**.

```
import subprocess
import sys
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

name = input("Enter the name of the object (the town, e.g. Lublin or Kock): ") #Lublin, Kock

query = "SELECT ST_Centroid(ogr_geocode('{}, województwo lubelskie'))".format(name)
command = ["ogrinfo", ":memory:", "-q", "-sql", query]

proc = subprocess.run(command,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      encoding="utf-8")

if proc.returncode:
    sys.exit("Failed to execute ogrinfo command.")

lines = proc.stdout.split('\n')

found = False
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("POINT"):
        found = True
        
        _, x, y = line.split()
        x = x.lstrip("(")
        y = y.rstrip(")")
        print("")
        print("{}:\n".format(name))
        print("WGS84 (EPSG: 4326) coordinates")
        print("longitude:  ", x)
        print("latitude:  ", y)
        print("")
        break
if not found:
    sys.exit("City not found.")
    
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:2180')
x1,y1 = x,y
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print("PUWG 1992 (EPSG: 2180) coordinates")
print ("X: ",x2)
print ("Y: ",y2)
```

Output

```
Enter the name of the object (the town, e.g. Lublin or Kock): Kock

Kock:

WGS84 (EPSG: 4326) coordinates
longitude:   22.4458062648351
latitude:   51.654282346758

PUWG 1992 (EPSG: 2180) coordinates
X:  738269.852848907
Y:  426492.45745886303
```

In Output, the script displays the coordinates of the city in EPSG:4326, and then in EPSG: 2180.

I have a DEM for all of Poland in the *Poland.tif* file, in the coordinate system EPSG: 2180.

How to extend the existing script so that from the *Poland.tif* raster cut a square fragment (with side length of 30 kilometers [18 miles]) with the center where the EPSG:2180 coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) on the input raster and use the [`-projwin`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-projwin)
argument to specify the bounds you require.

Since you know the position of the city `x` & `y` to calculate sides of your box is simple maths.

```
side = 30000 # 30km
h_side = side//2 # half a side (15km)
left = x - h_side
right = x + h_side
top = y + h_side
bottom = y - h_side
```

then simply call `gdal_translate -projwin left top right bottom ...`

Comment: Remember that the program first asks the user for the name of a city in Poland, for example Kock or Lublin. So the script will cut out a square fragment from the Poland.tif raster in a different place each time. Because the user will enter a different city each time. If the user enters the city name "Kock", then the program will return the same output as above in Output: X:  738269.852848907, Y:  426492.45745886303. These coordinates are the center of the square fragment being cut out.

Comment: that looks right - what doesn't work for you - there is an [edit] link so you can up date your question with new information

Comment: center X = 738269.852848907, center Y= 426492.45745886303 /// upper left X = center X - 15042.62285, upper left Y = center Y + 14964.55254 /// bottom right X = center X + 15042.62715, bottom right Y= center Y - 14968.69746 /// Above, I created mathematical formulas to get a square fragment around any Polish city (Lublin or Kock) entered by the user. /// gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry Poland.tif square.tif /// Can you help me complete these things ulx uly lrx lry so that it works for any entered Polish city?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much